# Does "using where" mean bad MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this MySQL query:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
SELECT img.id as iid,img.*,users.*,img.ave_rate as arate,img.count_rate as cn
FROM images AS img 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users on img.uid=users.id

WHERE img.id NOT IN (SELECT rates.imageid from rates WHERE rates.ip=1854604622) 
GROUP BY iid

ORDER BY
iid DESC
LIMIT 30
```

Its output says this:

```
1   PRIMARY             img     index       NULL         PRIMARY    4   NULL                30  580    Using where
1   PRIMARY             users   eq_ref      PRIMARY      PRIMARY    4   twtgirls3.img.uid   1   100 
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  rates   ref         imageid,ip   ip         5   const               4   100    Using where
```

As you can see in the first row it is using the PRIMARY key as index but in the extra column we have "Using Where", what does it mean? does it mean that the key is not used? We have the same condition in the third row....

And finally, what do you think about this query? Is it optimized?

Answer (score 0):

> If the Extra column also says Using where, it means the index is being used to perform lookups of key values. Without Using where, the optimizer may be reading the index to avoid reading data rows but not using it for lookups. For example, if the index is a covering index for the query, the optimizer may scan it without using it for lookups.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html